# How to resample a dictionary of dataframes (Yahoo Data) in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, grouping, dataframe

I want to download a bunch of data from yahoo finance, put it in a dictionary and do all sort of stuff with it. Starting with resampling it to a 'last bday of the quarter' or 'BQ - business quarter end frequency':

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as pdd

x = pdd.DataReader('VBK', data_source='yahoo', start='2004/1/30')
y = pdd.DataReader('IWM', data_source='yahoo', start='2000/5/26')
z = {'x': x, 'y': y}

conversion = {'Open': 'first', 'High': 'max', 'Low': 'min', 'Close': 'last', 'Volume': 'sum', 'Adj Close': 'last'}
for key, df in z.iteritems():
    df.resample('BQ', how=conversion)
```

But, nothing happens.  However, If I do:

```
 test = x.resample('BQ', how=conversion)
```

I get the desired outcome, but the issue is that I want to do this procedure for multiple dataframes. So the problem is in the for loop that applies the function.

Thanks

Comment: @Paul H I had a big mistake in the original question. However, a problem persists. The issue is with the iteration in the dict.

Comment: What makes you say that?. Doesn't the fact that the resample works for a single dataframe invalidate your point?

Comment: in python 3, the error i get is that dictionaries don't have an `iteritems` method.

Comment: @PaulH Thanks for the input. But I can run the resample with the same conversion as a dict. And it works fine. But for a single df. It's been used like that forever see this recipe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861023/resampling-minute-data

Comment: well when I correct your loop, it works for me. What makes you think it's not working? You're not reassigning the results back into `z`, so the whole process will be very ephemeral. You can replace your last line with `z[key] = df.resample('BQ', how=conversion)` to save the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python 3, there's no `iteritems` method of a dictionary. You're also not saving the output of the resampling method.

This works for me:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.data as pdd

x = pdd.DataReader('VBK', data_source='yahoo', start='2004/1/30')
y = pdd.DataReader('IWM', data_source='yahoo', start='2000/5/26')
z = {'x': x, 'y': y}

conversion = {
    'Open': 'first', 
    'High': 'max', 
    'Low': 'min', 
    'Close': 'last', 
    'Volume': 'sum', 
    'Adj Close': 'last'
}

for key, df in z.items():
    z[key] = df.resample('BQ', how=conversion)
```