# Truncating hourly Pandas Series to be full days only

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas 0.17.1 and I oftentimes encounter hourly Series data that contains partial days.  It does not seem that there is any functionality built into pandas that permits you to discard values that correspond to incomplete segments of a coarser date offset on the boundaries of the Series data (I would only like to discard partial data that exist at the beginning and/or the end of the Series).

My intuition, given the above, is that I would have to code something up to abstract the criterion (e.g. groupby with a count aggregation, discard hours in days with < 24 hours):

```
>> hist_data.groupby(lambda x: x.date()).agg('count')
2007-01-01    23
2007-01-02    24
...
```

An example of desired behavior:

```
>> hourly_data
2016-01-01 04:00:00    0.603820
2016-01-01 05:00:00    0.806696
2016-01-01 06:00:00    0.938521
2016-01-01 07:00:00    0.781834
2016-01-01 08:00:00    0.154952
...
2016-01-03 22:00:00    0.082177
2016-01-03 23:00:00    0.753210
2016-01-04 00:00:00    0.458402
2016-01-04 01:00:00    0.649496
2016-01-04 02:00:00    0.525321
2016-01-04 03:00:00    0.242605
Freq: H, dtype: float64

>> remove_partial_boundary_data(hourly_data)
2016-01-02 00:00:00    0.833063
2016-01-02 01:00:00    0.131586
2016-01-02 02:00:00    0.876609
2016-01-02 03:00:00    0.319436
2016-01-02 04:00:00    0.056246
...
2016-01-03 20:00:00    0.405725
2016-01-03 21:00:00    0.541096
2016-01-03 22:00:00    0.082177
2016-01-03 23:00:00    0.753210
Freq: H, dtype: float64
```

However, if my timezone is anything other than UTC (timezone-aware), the approach suggested above seems fraught with peril because counts of hours on DST transition days would be either 23 or 25.

Does anyone know of a clever or built-in way to handle this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861023/resampling-minute-data

Comment: Sorry, this is still not clear. How do you want to keep the frequency hourly, but do an aggregation? Can you show an example input and desired output?

Comment: Edited.  I do not want to 'do' an aggregation on the data.  I only thought naively that a count would help abstract my criteria for discarding.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a groupby and filter on groups that are not complete. To check for completeness, I first reindexed the data and then checked if there are NaN values:

```
In [10]: hourly_data = pd.Series(np.random.randn(72), index=pd.date_range('2016-01-01 04:00', periods=72, freq='H'))

In [11]: new_idx = pd.date_range(hourly_data.index[0].date(), hourly_data.index[-1].date() + pd.Timedelta('1 day'), freq='H')

In [12]: hourly_data.reindex(new_idx)
Out[12]:
2016-01-01 00:00:00         NaN
2016-01-01 01:00:00         NaN
2016-01-01 02:00:00         NaN
2016-01-01 03:00:00         NaN
2016-01-01 04:00:00   -0.941332
2016-01-01 05:00:00    1.802739
2016-01-01 06:00:00    0.798968
2016-01-01 07:00:00   -0.444979
                         ...
2016-01-04 17:00:00         NaN
2016-01-04 18:00:00         NaN
2016-01-04 19:00:00         NaN
2016-01-04 20:00:00         NaN
2016-01-04 21:00:00         NaN
2016-01-04 22:00:00         NaN
2016-01-04 23:00:00         NaN
2016-01-05 00:00:00         NaN
Freq: H, dtype: float64
```

This resulted in a timeseries that includes all hours of the dates that are present in the timeseries. This way, we can check if a date was complete by checking if there are NaN values for that date (this method should work for DST transitions), and filter with this criterion:

```
In [13]: hourly_data.reindex(new_idx).groupby(lambda x: x.date()).filter(lambda x: x.isnull().sum() == 0)
Out[13]:
2016-01-02 00:00:00   -1.231445
2016-01-02 01:00:00    2.371690
2016-01-02 02:00:00   -0.695448
2016-01-02 03:00:00    0.745308
2016-01-02 04:00:00    0.814579
2016-01-02 05:00:00    1.345674
2016-01-02 06:00:00   -1.491470
2016-01-02 07:00:00    0.407182
                         ...
2016-01-03 16:00:00   -0.742151
2016-01-03 17:00:00    0.677229
2016-01-03 18:00:00    0.832271
2016-01-03 19:00:00   -0.183729
2016-01-03 20:00:00    1.938594
2016-01-03 21:00:00   -0.816370
2016-01-03 22:00:00    1.745757
2016-01-03 23:00:00    0.223487
Freq: H, dtype: float64
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**
You can do this with `resample` by providing a custom function, and in that function you can then specify that NaN values should not be skipped.

Short answer:

```
hist_data.resample('D', how=lambda x: x.mean(skipna=False))
```

if the missing hours are already present as NaNs. Otherwise, you can first resample it to a regular hourly series:

```
hist_data.resample('H').resample('D', how=lambda x: x.mean(skipna=False))
```

---

Long answer with an example. With some dummy data (and I insert a NaN in one of the days):

```
In [77]: hist_data = pd.Series(np.random.randn(72), index=pd.date_range('2016-01-01', periods=72, freq='H'))

In [78]: hist_data
Out[78]:
2016-01-01 00:00:00   -0.717624
2016-01-01 01:00:00    0.029151
2016-01-01 02:00:00    0.535843
                         ...
2016-01-03 21:00:00    0.659923
2016-01-03 22:00:00   -1.085640
2016-01-03 23:00:00    0.571347
Freq: H, dtype: float64

In [80]: hist_data.iloc[30] = np.nan
```

With `count` you can see that there is indeed one missing value for the second day:

```
In [81]: hist_data.resample('D', how='count')
Out[81]:
2016-01-01    24
2016-01-02    23
2016-01-03    24
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

By default, `'mean'` will ignore this NaN value:

```
In [83]: hist_data.resample('D', how='mean')
Out[83]:
2016-01-01    0.106537
2016-01-02   -0.112774
2016-01-03   -0.292248
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

But you can change this behaviour with the `skipna` keyword argument:

```
In [82]: hist_data.resample('D', how=lambda x: x.mean(skipna=False))
Out[82]:
2016-01-01    0.106537
2016-01-02         NaN
2016-01-03   -0.292248
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Question was very poorly worded and I've edited to attempt to be more clear.  I apologize.