# Pandas .resample to get mean values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to resample 15 minute data to 60 minute data by using the pandas .resample function with the 'mean' method, but by default this method takes the average of the original value and the 3 next values. Is there a way to instead take the average of the original value and the 3 previous values?

Input data (in reality the input data is 365 days):

```
Generated On                CB_P
2019-01-01 08:15:00+00:00   0.187
2019-01-01 08:30:00+00:00   0.228
2019-01-01 08:45:00+00:00   0.242
2019-01-01 09:00:00+00:00   0.8270
2019-01-01 09:15:00+00:00   1.083
2019-01-01 09:30:00+00:00   3.022
2019-01-01 09:45:00+00:00   1.511
2019-01-01 10:00:00+00:00   1.568
2019-01-01 10:15:00+00:00   6.365
2019-01-01 10:30:00+00:00   8.23
2019-01-01 10:45:00+00:00   9.3
2019-01-01 11:00:00+00:00   14.311
2019-01-01 11:15:00+00:00   13.045
2019-01-01 11:30:00+00:00   11.05
2019-01-01 11:45:00+00:00   11.257
2019-01-01 12:00:00+00:00   13.367
2019-01-01 12:15:00+00:00   11.895
2019-01-01 12:30:00+00:00   9.245
2019-01-01 12:45:00+00:00   7.254
2019-01-01 13:00:00+00:00   15.773
2019-01-01 13:15:00+00:00   14.280
2019-01-01 13:30:00+00:00   17.258
2019-01-01 13:45:00+00:00   7.792
2019-01-01 14:00:00+00:00   6.893
2019-01-01 14:15:00+00:00   4.693
2019-01-01 14:30:00+00:00   4.271
2019-01-01 14:45:00+00:00   1.524
2019-01-01 15:00:00+00:00   1.495
2019-01-01 15:15:00+00:00   1.03
2019-01-01 15:30:00+00:00   0.364
2019-01-01 15:45:00+00:00   0.045
```

Expected output:

```
Generated On                CB_P
2019-01-01 09:00:00+00:00   0.371
2019-01-01 10:00:00+00:00   1.796
2019-01-01 11:00:00+00:00   9.5515
2019-01-01 12:00:00+00:00   12.180
2019-01-01 13:00:00+00:00   11.04
2019-01-01 14:00:00+00:00   11.556
2019-01-01 15:00:00+00:00   2.996
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resampling Minute data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861023/resampling-minute-data)

i.e.: df.resample('60Min', on='Generated On').mean()

Comment: The topic in that link is about starting at a different time, but that is not what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(df['Generated On'].hour)[['CB_P']].mean()
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that my data is not just 1 day, but 365 days (edited that now), so this method didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? You basically apply a 15-min offset on your original `datetime` column and then `resample`. And you can build multiple set or custom functions.

I'm using `pandas==1.1.3`. `df_Agg2` should be what you're after.

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats as stats
from datetime import timedelta


df = pd.read_csv(r't1.csv')
df['Generated On'] = pd.to_datetime( df['Generated On'] )
df['datetime_Adj'] = df['Generated On'] - timedelta(minutes=15)

lambda0 = lambda x: stats.mode(x)[0]
lambda1 = lambda x: x.max() - x.min()

##########################################################################

df_Agg1 = df.resample(rule='1H', on='Generated On').apply({ 
                'CB_P': ['sum', 'mean', 'min', 'max', lambda0, lambda1 ], 
                })

# Rename the columns
df_Agg1.columns = ['_'.join(pair) for pair in df_Agg1.columns]
df_Agg1.reset_index(inplace=True)

##########################################################################

df_Agg2 = df.resample(rule='1H', on='datetime_Adj').apply({ 
                'CB_P': ['sum', 'mean', 'min', 'max', lambda0, lambda1 ], 
                })

# Rename the columns
df_Agg2.columns = ['_'.join(pair) for pair in df_Agg2.columns]
df_Agg2.reset_index(inplace=True)

##########################################################################
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell `resample` to start each cycle 45 minutes earlier:

```
r = df.resample('1H', offset=pd.Timedelta("-00:45:00")).mean()
```

This yields the correct means but an incorrect (shifted) index. Fix it by shifting it by 45 minutes forward:

```
r.index += pd.Timedelta("00:45:00")
#                                CB_P
#Generated On                        
#2019-01-01 09:00:00+00:00   0.371000
#2019-01-01 10:00:00+00:00   1.796000
#2019-01-01 11:00:00+00:00   9.551500
#2019-01-01 12:00:00+00:00  12.179750
#2019-01-01 13:00:00+00:00  11.041750
#2019-01-01 14:00:00+00:00  11.555750
#2019-01-01 15:00:00+00:00   2.995750
#2019-01-01 16:00:00+00:00   0.479667
```